# undefined error when getting inventory quantity in NetSuite

Tags: javascript, netsuite

The issue I am having is I am consistently getting the following error when executing a user event script in NetSuite:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property "amazon" from undefined
```

NetSuite uses Javascript to do the business logic on both client and server side. For those without NetSuite experience, a user event script is executed on the server.

The code I can share is as follows:

```
var qtyAvail = 0; 
qtyAvail = rec.getValue('locationquantityavailable');
if(!qtyAvail || qtyAvail === 'undefined' || qtyAvail === null || isNaN(qtyAvail) || typeof qtyAvail === "undefined"){
                qtyAvail = 0;

            }   
  location = rec.getValue(kColumns[3]);
            if(location == 7 ||location == 16 ||location == 20 ||location == 3 ||location == 19 ||location == 1 ||location == 27 ||location == 27){    
                if(location == 7){
                    fba = qtyAvail;
                    if(!fba){
                        qtyAvail = 0;
                    }                    
                }
...more business code here....
 return {

            amazon: fba,
            ups: upsName
 }
```

I am calling the return values like:

```
var itemQty = getLocationQty(item);
           if(itemQty.amazon){
               var fbaStock = itemQty.amazon;
           } else { fbaStock = 0;}
```

This code works fine for some of my locations, but if there is not quantity available in a specific location it is returning undefined, rather then setting the qtyAvail to 0 as I would expect.

Am I missing a comparison for checking undefined anywhere, or does anyone else see any issues with the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the snippet you included it looks like you are not initializing the value of fba.

Add `var fba=0;` at the start and see if that fixes it.

Or perhaps you meant to assign qtyAvail to amazon instead of fba.

Comment: I've initialized fba to 0 with no luck. I am assigning qtyAvail to fba as when I do my return I am returning an associative array that I can pull the objects out of from outside of the function. 

What is odd, is that the code will work on some records fine and others will fail with undefined. A side by side comparison of the records show values are present in the fba location that is failing. Any other ideas? 

I am about to consider rewriting my functions, but i'd rather not if I can avoid it :)

Comment: Yes I have - I found the source of my grief though: Kit items are causing the failure, so I wrote a function that drops the kit part of the item name and returns the main sku. Since the change it seems to be working - I am currently running a batch of 200 sales orders to see how it performs.

Answer (score 1):

From the bits of code you did share and your original description it looks like the object literal you were returning from your function wasn't actually being returned.  'amazon' being a property of that object and since the error says it's undefined then that function was returning nothing.

Run the following code in a JS engine:

```
function foo()
{
    return;
}

alert( foo().amazon );
```

and you will see:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'amazon' of undefined

I see that you found a solution, I just don't see how it's related to your original problem you reported.  Am I missing something?

**Also**, although not part of your question I thought I might mention another approach to writing your location check, a little easier to read:

```
var acceptedLocations = [ 7, 16, 20, 3, 19, 1, 27 ];
if(acceptedLocations.indexOf(location) > 0)
{
  //  Do rad stuff
}
```

Comment: Thanks Steve, the solution I had had continued to fail under certain circumstances causing me to re-write the code, interestingly enough I used indexOf to support a cleaner design. +1 for your suggestion, Thanks.